# CDI ambiguous resolution with extended class

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I need to inject a `CacheService` into various beans as well as maintain a singleton extension of `CacheService` called `ResourceCacheService`.

```
interface CacheService{}
@Default
class CacheServiceImpl implements CacheService{}
@Singleton
class ResourceCacheService extends CacheServiceImpl{}
```

Or better yet:

```
interface ResourceCacheService extends CacheService{}
@Singleton
class ResourceCacheServiceImpl extends CacheServiceImpl{}
```

Either way, I get an ambiguous exception. How can I inject new instances of `CacheService` where needed, as well as create a `Singleton` version of it?

---

UPDATE - Added exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansDeploymentException: javax.enterprise.inject.AmbiguousResolutionException: There is more than one Bean with type com.project.cache.CacheServiceQualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]

ResourceCacheService, WebBeansType:MANAGED, Name:null, API Types:[com.project.web.ResourceCacheService,com.project.cache.CacheService,java.lang.Object,com.project.cache.CacheServiceImpl], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any] from file:/application/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/project/web/ResourceCacheService.class
CacheServiceImpl, WebBeansType:MANAGED, Name:null, API Types:[com.project.cache.CacheService,java.lang.Object,com.project.cache.CacheServiceImpl], Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Default,javax.enterprise.inject.Any] from file:/application/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/project/cache/CacheServiceImpl.class
```

Comment: you get an exception from defining? or injecting? does using `@Named` help? Or [CDI qualifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html)?

Comment: its a runtime exception during cdi init. provide a @Named example in my scenario

Comment: Runtime exception can be either or. It would be helpful if you'd actually provide the exception you're getting in your question so we don't have to guess.

Comment: added exception. im aware of `@Named` and CDI qualifiers but would like to avoid if possible. thought im thinking `@Named` makes sense here

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have an inheritance chain C extends B extends A and want to use C and B in different scenarios. This cannot be done without further qualifying the classes, thus either create a different inheritance scenario:

```
interface CacheServiceBase
StandardCacheService implements CacheServiceBase
GlobalCacheService implements CacheServiceBase

// Injection of different things which do *not* extend each other
@Inject StandardCacheService
@Inject GlobalCacheService
```

or use a qualifier annotation to further distinguish the implementations. See here how to do it: https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html

Comment: problem is `StandardCacheService` and `GlobalCacheService` implementations would be duplicates. how is that avoided? i need them both to extend base functionality

Comment: Why would they be duplicates? Or are you referring to not-being-global? In that case, use the `@ApplicationScoped` annotation

Comment: dont wanna inject concretes, defeats the purpose of CDI. going with qualifier annotations